# How to sort list by using specific rules

Tags: python, list, sortedlist

Hi I have complicated data objects that I want to sort through s. Simplified version below:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
```

Each of this data objects will be placed in specific category for easy use later. Simplified version again below

```
class DataCategory(object):
    def __init__(self, id1, id2, linked_data=None):
        self.id1 = id1
        self.id2 = id2
        self.ld = linked_data
```

I want to sort data below by their s number BUT There are few more rules. If one data object was used from first data collection I want to use one from second collection IF s number is same or lower. Here is what I get and what I want to achieve

```
# order I get
# [['p02g01r05', 5], ['p02g01r01', 4], ['p01g01r05', 4], ['p01g01r01', 3], ['p01g01r02', 2], ['p01g01r03', 2], ['p01g01r06', 2], ['p02g01r02', 2], ['p02g01r03', 2], ['p02g01r04', 2], ['p01g01r04', 1], ['p02g01r06', 1]]
# order I want
# [['p02g01r05', 5], ['p01g01r05', 4], ['p02g01r01', 4], ['p01g01r01', 3], ['p02g01r02', 2], ['p01g01r02', 2], ['p02g01r03', 2], ['p01g01r03', 2], ['p02g01r04', 2], ['p01g01r06', 2], ['p02g01r06', 1]], ['p01g01r04', 1]
```

This is what I created so far but I'm thinking that I'm going in wrong direction with this. List of indexes to replace is correct I think.

```
# Some data objects
p01g01r01 = Data(3)
p01g01r02 = Data(2)
p01g01r03 = Data(2)
p01g01r04 = Data(1)
p01g01r05 = Data(4)
p01g01r06 = Data(2)

p02g01r01 = Data(4)
p02g01r02 = Data(2)
p02g01r03 = Data(2)
p02g01r04 = Data(2)
p02g01r05 = Data(5)
p02g01r06 = Data(1)

p01g01 = DataCategory("01", "01", [])
p02g01 = DataCategory("02", "01", [])


# link data to data category
def ldtdc(dc):
    lst = []
    data = "p" + dc.id1 + "g" + dc.id2 + "r"
    for i in range(1, 7):
        if i < 10:
            lst.append(data + "0" + str(i))
        else:
            lst.append(data + str(i))
    return lst

p01g01.ld = ldtdc(p01g01)
p02g01.ld = ldtdc(p02g01)


# /@= This starts to get way too complicated fast ############################
def lstu(ag, dg):
    lst = []
    # data list of first collection
    dlofc = []
    # data list of second collection
    dlosc = []

    # for every data unit that exists in data collection
    for unit in ag.ld:
        # lst.append([unit, globals()[unit].s+10])
        lst.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])
        dlofc.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])

    for unit in dg.ld:
        lst.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])
        dlosc.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])

    # lambda function is used here to sort list by data value ([1] is index of the item)
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # current index
    ci = 0

    previous_data = ["last data unit will be stored here", 0]
    # sorted list
    slst = []

    for unit in lst:
        try:
            next_data = lst[ci+1]
        except IndexError:
            next_data = ["endoflist", 0]
        if previous_data[0] == "last data unit will be stored here":
            pass
        elif previous_data[0][:6] == unit[0][:6]:
            if unit[0][:6] not in dlofc[0][0]:
                slst.append([unit[0], unit[1], ci])
            elif unit[0][:6] not in dlosc[0][0]:
                slst.append([unit[0], unit[1], ci])
            else:
                print "Error"

        previous_data = unit
        ci += 1

    print "slist below"
    print slst

    return lst
# \@= END #####################################################################


print p01g01.ld
print p02g01.ld


data_list = lstu(p01g01, p02g01)
print data_list
```

What is the quick and correct way to sort this data?

Comment: Have you considered the `sorted` function or `list.sort` method?

Comment: in example above you can see that I already used sorted but it is not enough to fulfill all requirements of new list

Comment: Do you know/realize that you can control the way `sorted` and `list.sort` compare the element when sorting? Once you can control that I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use `sorted` or `list.sort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. New lstu function:

```
# replaced lambda with normal function
def get_key(item):
    return item[1]


def lstu(ag, dg):
    # ag list
    agslst = []
    # dg list
    dgslst = []

    # for every unit in first data collection
    for unit in ag.u:
        agslst.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])
    # sorted first data collection list
    agslst = sorted(agslst, key=get_key, reverse=True)
    print agslst

    for unit in dg.u:
        dgslst.append([unit, globals()[unit].s])
    # 2nd collection sorted list
    dgslst = sorted(dgslst, key=get_key, reverse=True)
    print dgslst

    lst = []
    # last item
    li = ["Empty", 0]

    for item in range(0, len(agslst)+len(dgslst)+1):
        if agslst and dgslst:
            if agslst[0][1] == dgslst[0][1]:
                if li[0][:6] == agslst[0][0][:6]:
                    li = dgslst.pop(0)
                    lst.append(li)
                else:
                    li = agslst.pop(0)
                    lst.append(li)

            elif agslst[0][1] > dgslst[0][1]:
                li = agslst.pop(0)
                lst.append(li)
            else:
                li = dgslst.pop(0)
                lst.append(li)

    return lst
```

In this way I fulfill earlier mentioned requirements for new (and final) list

Output:

```
[['p02g01r05', 5], ['p01g01r05', 4], ['p02g01r01', 4], ['p01g01r01', 3], ['p02g01r02', 2], ['p01g01r02', 2], ['p02g01r03', 2], ['p01g01r03', 2], ['p02g01r04', 2], ['p01g01r06', 2], ['p02g01r06', 1]], ['p01g01r04', 1]]
```

I'm open for any optimization suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sorting by string first and then sort by number in items?

```
>>> items = [['p02g01r05', 5], ['p02g01r01', 4], ['p01g01r05', 4], ['p01g01r01', 3], ['p01g01r02', 2], ['p01g01r03', 2], ['p01g01r06', 2], ['p02g01r02', 2], ['p02g01r03', 2], ['p02g01r04', 2], ['p01g01r04', 1], ['p02g01r06', 1]]
>>> partially_sorted = sorted(items, key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)
>>> sorted(partially_sorted, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
[['p02g01r05', 5], ['p02g01r01', 4], ['p01g01r05', 4], ['p01g01r01', 3], ['p02g01r04', 2], ['p02g01r03', 2], ['p02g01r02', 2], ['p01g01r06', 2], ['p01g01r03', 2], ['p01g01r02', 2], ['p02g01r06', 1], ['p01g01r04', 1]]
```

Comment: It won't work. There should be one item from p01g01 and then one item from p02g01 if they have same "s". In example above we will get many items with the same "s" from the same collection.

Comment: Is it basically merging two sorted lists? One sorted list called p01g01 and other being p02g01?

Comment: No, python sort is stable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability